# Put entire OS X home folder into Google Drive

Tags: macos, user-account, google-apps

I know it's possible to relocate the home folder on the mac to somewhere other than `/Users/[username]`. But would it be possible to move it to, say, `/Users/[username]/Google Drive` without messing up the Google Drive app which syncs files between the computer and the cloud?

Comment: Some directories would probably not be synced e.g. ~/Libray/Caches, ~/Downloads as they contain data which changes often and does not need yo be kept

Comment: I really really DO NOT recommend this. But yes, it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** OS X sees the Google Drive folder as any other folder, so there is no problem putting your home folder there, providing you don't asynchronously write to core Library files, using Drive is fine.